# Parse.com multiple background jobs, performance issue

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

Jack here. I am developing an app and I wish to display a few items in a collectionView in iOS and grid view in Android. I wish to display an Item's image, name, price, and then seller's profile image, name, and last log in.

Basically there is three background job + one cloud code job for every cell. Find item image, find seller, find seller profile image, and check if current user liked the item yet.

While writing the iOS app, the code is working alright. The following is my cellForItemAtIndexPath method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Initing an iKard
    itemCell *cell = (itemCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"itemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    PFObject *item = [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.objectId = [item objectId];

    [cell.itemNameLabel setText:[item objectForKey:@"name"]];
    float priceInCent = [[item objectForKey:@"priceInCent"] floatValue];
    float price = priceInCent/100.0f;
    [cell.itemPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.02f", price]];
    PFFile *imageFile = [item objectForKey:@"itemImage"];
    if (imageFile != nil) {
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [cell.itemImageView setImage:image];
            } else {
                [self displayErrorMessage:error];
            }
        }];
    }

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userLikedItemWithId"
                       withParameters:@{@"objectId":[item objectId]}
                                block:^(NSNumber *liked, NSError *error) {
                                    if ([liked isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
                                        [cell.likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like0"]
                                                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                    } else if ([liked isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
                                        [cell.likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like1"]
                                                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                    }
                                }];



    PFUser *seller = [item objectForKey:@"owner"];
    [seller fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *seller, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            //Setting seller info
            //Name
            [cell.profileNameLabel setText: [seller objectForKey:@"displayName"]];

            //Last visit
            NSString *lastVisit = [NSString new];
            NSDate *updatedAt = seller.updatedAt;
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            NSInteger differenceInDays = [self daysBetweenDate:updatedAt
                                                        andDate:now];
            if (differenceInDays == 0) {
                lastVisit = @"Today";
            } else {
                lastVisit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days ago", (long)differenceInDays];
            }
            [cell.profileLastVisitLabel setText:lastVisit];

            //Profile image
            PFFile *imageFile = [seller objectForKey:@"profileImage"];
            if (imageFile != nil) {
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [cell.profileImageView setImage:image];
                        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    } else {
                        [self displayErrorMessage:error];
                    }
                }];
            }
        } else {
            [self displayErrorMessage:error];
        }
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

However when I pretty copy paste and then translated object-C to Java, things started to get messy. It takes significantly longer for Android real device to download a file, than it would take if running on a iOS real device. As I have four background jobs going on, it takes ages to get even one item downloaded and displayed. If I start scrolling, the cell just gets messed up.
The following is my getView method in gridView adapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View cell, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) this.mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell, viewGroup, false);

//        [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

ParseObject item = this.itemList.get(position);

//        cell.objectId = [item objectId];

        TextView itemNameTextView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView);
        itemNameTextView.setText(item.getString("name"));

        float priceInCent = item.getLong("priceInCent");
        float price = priceInCent/100.0f;
        String P= "$" + Float.toString(price);
        TextView itemPriceTextView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemPriceTextView);
        itemPriceTextView.setText(P);

        final ImageView itemImageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView);
        ParseFile imageFile = item.getParseFile("itemImage");
        imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
          public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
              // data has the bytes for the resume
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                itemImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
            } else {
              // something went wrong
                displayErrorMessage(e);
            }
          }
        });

        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("objectId", item.getObjectId());
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("userLikedItemWithId", params, new FunctionCallback<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void done(Integer liked, ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    displayErrorMessage(e);
                    return;
                }
                if (liked == 0) {

                } else if (liked == 1) {

                }
            }
        });


        final TextView profileNameTextView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.profileNameTextView);
        final TextView profileLastVisitTextView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.profileLastVisitTextView);
        final ImageView profileImageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);

        ParseUser seller = item.getParseUser("owner");
        seller.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
              public void done(ParseObject seller, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    //Setting seller info
                    //Name
                    profileNameTextView.setText(seller.getString("displayName"));
                    //Last visit
                    Date lastVisit = seller.getUpdatedAt();
                    Date now = new Date();
                    long diff = now.getTime() - lastVisit.getTime();
                    int diffInDays = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    String lastVisited= Float.toString(diffInDays);
                    profileLastVisitTextView.setText(lastVisited);

                    if (diffInDays == 0) {
                        profileLastVisitTextView.setText("Today");
                    } else {
                        profileLastVisitTextView.setText(lastVisited + "days ago");
                    }


                    //Profile image
                    ParseFile imageFile = seller.getParseFile("profileImage");
                    imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                      public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                          // data has the bytes for the resume
                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                            profileImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                        } else {
                          // something went wrong
                            displayErrorMessage(e);
                        }
                      }
                    });
                } else {
                    displayErrorMessage(e);
                }
              }
            });

        return cell;
    }
```

And things gets worse since Android tends to call getView multiple times for a single cell. After I scroll for a little bit, app just crashes due to too many background jobs.

My question is, 
Firstly, is the difference caused by the performance difference of Android real device and iOS real device? (It's a new android, 2g ram, 4 core, bought for future proof purpose, vs 2 year old iPhone 4s)
Secondly, if the above is correct, is there any way I can probably increase the performance? Am I coding properly?
Thank you of much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answers. The app crashes due to the memory issue. I was loading to many images into the gridView.
I've found a few ways to over come this. Basically there are two steps required.
First, start a process dialog, download the data in doInBackground method.
After downloading it, cashing it into memory or on to disk.
This is how to do it.
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-gridview-tutorial/
I copied most of the codes, and modified a bit to fit my Parse Data. But those memory cache and storage are really helpful.